# Hover Effect in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have this code to make every box light up when the mouse is on that block
but it's not working I guess i can do the effect properly if i used Rectangles instead of loading images but it wouldn't look cool
so any idea on how to get that damned effect?

```
import pygame , os ,sys
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode(300,300)
x_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images', "x.png"))
o_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images', "o.png"))

class Box:
    hoverd = False
    def __init__(self, height, width, x, y):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.img = self.is_hover()

    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.img, (self.x, self.y)

    def is_hover(self):
        if self.hoverd:
            return pygame.image.load(os.path.join(resource_dir, "box_hover.png"))
        else:
            return pygame.image.load(os.path.join(resource_dir, "box.png"))

board_boxes = [Box(0, 0, 0, 0)] * 10
def draw_board(window):
    global board_boxes
    for y in (0, 100, 200):
        for x in (0, 100, 200):
            index = 1
            box = Box(100, 100, x, y)
            board_boxes[index] = box
            box.draw(window)
            index += 1

draw_board(win) 
run = True
while run:
    board = [" "] * 10
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pass

    for box in board_boxes:
        if pos[0] > box.x and pos[0] < box.x + box.width:
            if pos[1] > box.y and pos[1] < box.y + box.height:
                box.hoverd = True
            else:
                box.hoverd = False

    pygame.display.update()
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `is_hover()` to assign image in `__init__` and expect it will change image when mouse hovers button.

You should load both images in `__init__` and use `self.hoverd` in `draw()` to display different image.

And you have to use `draw()` in `while True` to draw all boxes after all tests.

```
class Box:
    def __init__(self, height, width, x, y):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        self.hoverd = False

        self.img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(resource_dir, "box.png"))
        self.img_hovered = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(resource_dir, "box_hover.png"))

    def draw(self, window):
        if self.hoverd:
            window.blit(self.img_hovered, (self.x, self.y))
        else
            window.blit(self.img, (self.x, self.y))

# create object without drawing

board_boxes = []

for y in (0, 100, 200):
    for x in (0, 100, 200):
        box = Box(100, 100, x, y)
        board_boxes.append(box)

# mainloop

run = True

while run:

    # --- events ---

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # --- changes/moves ---

    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    for box in board_boxes:
        if pos[0] > box.x and pos[0] < box.x + box.width:
            if pos[1] > box.y and pos[1] < box.y + box.height:
                box.hoverd = True
            else:
                box.hoverd = False

    # --- draws ---

    # pygame.screen.fill( (0,0,0) ) # clear screen with black color

    for box in board_boxes:
         box.draw(window)

    pygame.display.update()

# end

pygame.quit()
```

---

Using `pygame.Rect()` you could write it shorter ...

```
class Box:
    def __init__(self, height, width, x, y):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)

        self.hoverd = False

        self.img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(resource_dir, "box.png"))
        self.img_hovered = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(resource_dir, "box_hover.png"))

    def draw(self, window):
        if self.hoverd:
            window.blit(self.img_hovered, self.rect)
        else
            window.blit(self.img, self.rect)

# create object without drawing

board_boxes = []

for y in (0, 100, 200):
    for x in (0, 100, 200):
        box = Box(100, 100, x, y)
        board_boxes.append(box)

# mainloop

run = True

while run:

    # --- events ---

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # --- changes/moves ---

    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    for box in board_boxes:
        box.hoverd = box.rect.collidepoint(pos)

    # --- draws ---

    # pygame.screen.fill( (0,0,0) ) # clear screen with black color

    for box in board_boxes:
         box.draw(window)

    pygame.display.update()

# end

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: It would be a lot more efficient to draw everything once at the beginning and save a background view then just blit the images if hoverd==True.